# Matching days of week for a given date range

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am working on a space booking system and is trying to find out if the space is available for a given date range. So I have 2 tables -

```
space_master
    id    space_address   start_time    end_time

space_availability
    space_id    days_of_week
```

Note -

(a) start_time and end_time are DATETIME fields in MYSQL

(b) days_of_week are numbers where Sunday is represented by 1 and so on

(c) one space can be available on multiple days (example follows)

```
space_master    
id  space_address   start_time                  end_time

1   Florida         2012-03-18 10:21:00         2012-03-29 4:21:00
2   London          2012-04-21 09:00:00         2012-06-18 10:00:00

space_availability
space_id    days_of_week
1           1
1           2
2           4
2           5
2           6
```

This means the first space (with id 1) is available between 2012-03-18 10:21:00 and 2012-03-29 4:21:00 but only on Sunday and Monday. Now I am trying to write a function that will take booking_start_time and booking_end_time (all DATETIME in MYSQL) as input then scan the available spaces table and return the availble bookings. Something like this -

getBooking(2012-03-19 10:21:00, 2012-03-19 15:21:00) - returns the space with id 1 (as 19th March 2012 was a Monday and hence available)

getBooking(2012-03-19 10:21:00, 2012-03-20 15:21:00) - returns nothing since 20th March is a Tuesday on which the space is not available.

Any idea how to do this? I was first trying to do this in a single query. But is that even possible?

EDIT: the sqlfiddle link follows -

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a6e1a

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a6e1a

Comment: the Basic is quite simple, the real Task is getting all the Dates in a given timespan, there are several approaches out there but until now i couln't find something useful (without a secondary date-table)